# Could not execute method of the activity httpdata

Tags: android

What do you think is wrong with this code ? 
I am using this class: https://github.com/btouchard/HttpData/blob/master/README.md

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Location of error: Log.i line!
```

Thanks for the assistance.
I guess it is a basic solution, but I can't find it.

```
public class Formulaire extends Activity {

EditText msgTextField;
Button sendButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form);

    //make message text field object
    msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
    //make button object
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);



}

public void send(View v) {
    //get message from message box

    try {
        String MonURL = "http://www.davidmarchioni.fr/glopper/test.txt";

        HttpData request = new HttpData(MonURL);
        request.header(MonURL);
        String html = request.asString();
        Thread.sleep(2600);
        Log.i("OK >> ", html);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), html, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: If the `Log.i()` call is throwing an `Exception`, then `html` is probably `null`.

Answer (score 0):

well try on catching Exception, what if String html comes null? what maybe the reason